# Four bar linkage moment transmission

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-dynamics, torque, moment

[image: System]The question is.

I know the angular velocity of $d$ after applying dynamic mechanics and the constant angular velocity of $b$ of $2\pi\ \text{rad/s}$ and I know the input moment of the power source (motor).

Can I assume that the power transmitted from the motor (power source) is the same in $d$, and thus find the moment transmitted to the output, by the ratio of angular velocity between $d$ and $b$?

I want to find the output moment in $d$. Or should I in stead go by the length ratios between $b$ and $d$?

Comment: A diagram would help here.

Comment: I now added it :)

Comment: Is this: http://ocw.metu.edu.tr/pluginfile.php/3957/mod_resource/content/0/ch7/7-1.htm the kind of mechanism you're looking at?

Comment: Yes thank you :) But I'm a bit unsure how to calculate the moment. It only says something about the angular velocity, which I did calculate. But I want to find the function of the moment in D in terms of the input angular. I've already found the angular speed in D in terms of the input angle (from 0:360 degrees).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Four bar transmission.]

Assume all bars are rigid (un-deformable) and massless and all connecting points frictionless.

It's fairly self-evident that:

$$\frac{\omega_b}{|d|}=\frac{\omega_d}{|b|},$$

because of the rigid connection between $P_1$ and $P_2$ and because the sum of the angles in any quadrilateral is always $2\pi$, so:

$$\omega_b=\frac{|d|}{|b|}\omega_d$$

But there's information missing in this problem.

Assuming a constant torque $\tau_b$ acts on $b$, then the whole system would simply continue to accelerate.

But if we assume $d$ *drives something*, then:

$$\tau_b \omega_b=\tau_d\omega_d$$

The system would then move in a state of constant motion. To reach that steady state, for some time:

$$\tau_b>\tau_d,$$

as this would cause acceleration until $\omega_b$ is reached.

Comment: Thanks! Yes there's a mass in Td. We just wanted to know, if it the Power Transmitted is the same. And since Tb*Wb = Td*Wd then the Power Transmitted is the same. And thus Td/Tb = Wb/Wd.